# Generated url have false scheme

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

When I generate a url or a user logout in my application the url is `https` instead of the current protocol `http`. Can I force that all generated urls by symfony are http?

Twig URL Example:

```
{{ url('app.control') }} // https://myapp.com/control instead of http://myapp.com/control
``

Or in the security.yml:

`security
    firewalls:
        app:
            logout:
                path: app.logout
                target: app.login`

when he logout he will be redirected to htts instead of the current protocol http and will get a certificate error.

The application is running on a subdomain. I have another application on the main domain which use always https. But dont know why my application dont use the current http scheme to generate urls.

Answer (score 0):

Did cost me many time until I found the error in my VHOST configuration

```
fastcgi_params HTTPS false;
```

but should be:

```
fastcgi_params HTTPS off;
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction. Forgot that I had this option set to ON ...